# Cypress not catching XHR request

Tags: testing, mocking, cypress, ui-testing, gui-testing

I have made a simple cypress test and I want to start mocking the responses.

So in my `beforeEach` method I have the following

```
    cy.server()
    cy.route({
        method: "POST",
        url: "/perf/performance/track",
        status: 200,
        response: {}
    });
```

However it is not being triggered. The cypress UI displays the route as stubbed but not hit.

However I do see this in the console, which I find odd since it means that cypress knows about the call, right=

```
POST /perf/performance/track 503 32.261 ms - -
```

So any ideas of what the issue might be or where to start looking?

Just realized that even though it is shown in the cypress console, it is not being displayed withing the cypress GUI

Comment: Please show the complete test, the position of the command that triggers `POST` in the app is important.

Answer (score 1):

@munHunter Have you tried to investigate why do you have 503 error?

I wrote your test with my URL and it works fine.

Comment: I have not investigated why I am getting a 503 error as I find it quite irrelevant, since a call is being made and it is not caught be cypress. If everything would be working then the cypress mock should step in and reply with 200 OK

Comment: @TDK I know, I didn't have permission to comment.

Comment: I suggest to write only answers in answer post, until you gain enough reputation to comment; your post as is risk to be down-voted.